# Automatically chunk large mysql query

Tags: mysql

So lets say I have an update query that has 100m rows to do or equally an insert select with a similar number. Mysql doesn't ever actually do the insert or update on the table straight away.  Although a `SHOW TABLE STATUS` does give a hint at the progress if you browse the table it remains empty.

Is there a way you can run large queries but force Mysql to actually dump the data in the process? I'm not talking about already exported/re-imported data I'm talking about queries run live on the database. For example:

`UPDATE table SET FieldA = FieldB CHUNK 1000` - aka every 1000 records actually dump the result set

Comment: Afaik there is no general way to do this. "clever" tricks can be invented for specific cases, e.g: `WHERE id%10=0 ... WHERE id%10=1 ...`. It depends on what problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: I guess so I can capture the data along the way rather than it failing at the last minute.